# How to handle Pageable on Controller layout with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, boot

We have a Pageable object that is related to data layout, and it should be used in that context. How can we manage pagination in the controller layout without using the Pageable object? Perhaps there is a similar object for the controller layout

I've attempted to implement it this way,

`@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "0") Integer page, @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "20") Integer size, @RequestParam(required = false) String... sort`

but encountered issues with sorting. It doesn't parse as a pair of values necessary for Spring, for example, it needs to be in the form of 'id,ASC,' but it parses as two separate items

Comment: If you need a single parameter value then you should adjast the parameter mapping type.

Comment: @RomanC The goal is to support all functionalities from Pageable, including sorting by fields and direction, similar to the Sort class.
I could create manual proccesing is Service layout but it's not good aprouch

Comment: Sort is not a primitive type and it requires for Spring to know how to instantiate a parameter as object. It doesn't work as list or array.

Comment: Why not use the `Pageable`? Spring Data provides a special handler for this for controllers, so why not use that but try to workaround that and create your own half-baked implementation?

Comment: Could you explain why you don't want to use `Pageable`?  In my opinion, it doesn't make sense to try to implement your own solution when the framework provides this for free.

Answer (score 0):

When you do something like „values=5,7” in your url, then Spring will receive it as an array:

```
values[0] == 5
values[1] == 7
```

you can use this mechanics to get sorted attribute from element 0 and the direction from element 1 and then convert them into the pair you need

so you end up with something like this:

url = „[urlBase]&sort=id,DESC”

```
sortedAttribute = sort[0] //id
sortingDirection = sort[1] //DESC
```

and you can make the pair from those values. i cant help you with this because i am not sure what kind of pair you are talking about